# One Shop, Two ISPs. Will this work?

Tags: routing, networking

My retail shop uses Comcast Cable (calling it CC going forward) as the ISP. I just added Verizon 5G Business internet (calling it VZ going forward) as the backup for the times when CC is down (which has been more often than I like).

The LAN IP for the CC router is 10.1.10.1

The LAN IP for the VZ router is 192.168.0.1

The problem is that every time when a device connects to the VZ network, it will get assigned, by the VZ router, the default gateway of 192.168.0.1 and an IP in the 192.168.0.x range, which is fine, but when I'd connect back to the CC network, somehow the 192.168.0.1 default gateway and the 192.168.0.x IP get stuck in the device. Now, this device cannot be seen in the CC network nor can it go to the internet. I have to manually renew the IP on the device so that it will go back to 10.1.10.1 default gateway and a 10.1.10.x IP.

I am thinking:

I will change the VZ router’s LAN IP to be the same as the CC router's 10.1.10.1

I will then set the VZ router’s DHCP range to be the same range as that in the CC router.

We would NOT connect to the VZ network unless CC is down. This should avoid the conflict of having two routers with the same LAN IP.

Will this solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to let your clients decide where to go when is the hard way. Host configurations are off topic here, so we can't much comment on that.

The easier way is to use a router that decides which uplink to use. Most business-grade routers can use more than one WAN link. You can run the links in active/passive mode, or distribute load between them when both links are up (by e.g. source, destination or protocol) and fail over to the other side when one drops.

Very often a link doesn't fail on the physical layer (ie. link loss) but it just fails to provide connectivity. Your router should be able to monitor connectivity to a known-good service (sometimes called SLA with ping) and use that to decide where to route.

> I will change the VZ router’s LAN IP to be the same as the CC router's 10.1.10.1
> I will then set the VZ router’s DHCP range to be the same range as that in the CC router.
> We would NOT connect to the VZ network unless CC is down. This should avoid the conflict of having two routers with the same LAN IP.

You should only have one DHCP service running, not conflicting ones handing out addresses from the same scope. Even if you use a single IP subnet, your clients still have to decide which default gateway to use. Unless you implement a router redundancy protocol with a virtual IP (VRRP or HSRP) you'd need to move the LAN IP from one router to the other or reconfigure all clients. That seems troublesome.

Comment: But I am connecting to only one network at a time (normally we will NOT be connecting to the VZ network.)

Comment: Then it's the active/passive scenario above. Remember, it should be *you* who's defining your network, not some ISP router.